# feathersjs sequalize Belongs-To-Many associations Invalid value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am upgrading an Express application to Feathersjs application. I have the following model definition for belongs_to_many associations:

Clase A (usergroup):

```
  userGroup.associate = function (models) { 
    models.user_group.belongsToMany(models.permission, {through: 'user_group_permission'});
  };
```

Class B (permission):

```
  permission.associate = function (models) { 
    models.permission.belongsToMany(models.user_group, {through: 'user_group_permission'});
  };
```

With that definition, we sould be able to create a group and use the `addPermission/addPermissions` method to associate permissions to a group.

The following code intends to associate permissions with a group

```
      newGroup = await Model.create({
        groupName: data.groupName
      });
      newGroup.addPermissions(plist);
```

where `Model` is the variable for the UserGroup model class, and `plist` is a list of Permisssions.

This code is written in a service class generated by the `feathers generate service` command. Following this [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720002/how-to-override-feathersjs-defaults-service-methods), I overwrote  the create method. The goal is to work with the permission list provided in create group endpoint.

The result is this one:

[image: Rejection]

In the following image we can see the cause of the exception
[image: The stacktrace]

What is wrong with models definition if with Express application the same code works fine?

Comment: `addObject`, `addObjects` methods are documented [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html)

Comment: I think I am going to redefine my model in oder to eliminate the associations al become the associations in new models